# Angularjs functions after decode

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm trying to put some html content coming from php to a div with angularjs.

I'm encoding the html content in php with **rawurlencode()**. Here's what I do alongside my html content

```
$tempQ = "
    <div class='container'  data-ng-controller='formCtrl as fctrl'>
        <div class='card row'>
        <table class='table' width='100%';>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>
        <h3 class='f-400'>Kredi Hesaplama</h3>
        </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <div  class='card-body card-padding'>
                <h4 class='f-500'>Tutar: <span style='font-size:17pt;'>{{ fctrl.nouisliderValue }} </span> TL</h4>
                <div slider class='input-slider' ng-model='fctrl.nouisliderValue' start='1000' end='10000' data-is-color='red'></div> 
                <br/><br/>
                <h4 class='f-500'>Vade Miktarı: <span style='font-size:17pt;'>{{ fctrl.nouisliderValue2 }} </span> Ay</h4>
                <div slider class='input-slider' ng-model='fctrl.nouisliderValue2' start=1 end=36 data-is-color='red'></div> 
            </div>
            </td>
            <td style='background-color:#F44336;'>
            <br/>
                    <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6' style='width:100%;height:100%'>
                        <div class='color-block bgm-red'>
                            <span class='color' style='font-size:10pt'>Aylık Ödeme:</span>
                            <span class='code' style='font-size:24pt'>{{ fctrl.nouisliderValue/fctrl.nouisliderValue2 | number:2}}</span> TL
                        </br>
                            <span class='code' style='font-size:10pt'> Faiz tutarı: 1.12%</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>  
    </div>";

     $temp = rawurlencode($tempQ);

    $result_str .= "<IMAGE_SOURCE>$temp</IMAGE_SOURCE>\n";
```

Then I'm decoding and using this within my main controller in angular like this:

```
  if (data[i].resultCode == "success") {
        $scope.maps = true;
        $scope.OneBoxParse=decodeURIComponent(data[i].MODULE_RESULT.IMAGE_SOURCE);
  }
```

And like this in html side

```
<div ng-show="maps">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div  class="card" ng-bind-html="OneBoxParse | unsafe">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**| unsafe** is my trustAsHtml filter.

Problem is after all these, I end up with something like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZnEP.jpg)

What can I do to make angular recognize stuff within {{ }} ?

Comment: I think you need to recompile this with angular, i don't remember how to do that, perhaps it will help you..